# QT charts: How to get range of QAbstractAxis?

Tags: c++, qt

So I know that several children of the class QAbstractAxis has the function max() which returns the max range value on the axis. Is there any way to get this max value from QAbstractAxis, specifically after calling createDefaultAxes()?

Comment: There seems to be no virtual function to _get_ the range. I only found member functions to _set_ the range. However, [`QChart::createDefaultAxes()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#createDefaultAxes) documents the type of created axis instances depending on contents. Hence, a `dynamic_cast<>` can be used to adjust the type of retrieved axis pointer and then call the resp. `max()` method. (To become bullet-proof, the returned pointer of `dynamic_cast` can be checked before to be non-`nullptr`.)

Comment: I tried doing this, but it doesnt seem to work properly. Since I'm using a QLineSeries for the axis I figured it would default to a QValueAxis. Maybe I have to change the QLineSeries to another data type? qreal tempMax = dynamic_cast<QValueAxis*>(this->chart()->axisY())->max();

Comment: `QLineSeries` is inherited from `QXYSeries`. According to doc. `QXYSeries` should have `QValueAxis` for horizontal and vertical default axis. I don't know `axisY()`. `QChart` only offers [`axes()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#axes) which returns `QList<QAbstractAxis*>`. Are you using something derived? May be, you should [edit] your Q to add a [mcve]. (It's a bit "fishing in the fog"...) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to directly get the range from an `QAbstractAxis` - I suppose this is since the type of for the ranges `QAbstractAxis` might be e.g. `QString` ([QBarCategoryAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbarcategoryaxis.html)), `QDateTime` ([QDateTimeAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeaxis.html)), or `qreal`([QLogValueAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlogvalueaxis.html) and [QValueAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalueaxis.html) ).

You might try the slightly unelegant solution to `dynamic_cast<>` the `QAbstractAxis` to the various derived Axis types, and then directly read the `min` / `max` properties from the downcast type. Be mindful to have a safe fallback handling in case you encounter a custom Axis type that directly derives from `QAbstractAxis`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way of doing it. But following function should do the trick.

```
QPair<QVariant, QVariant> axisRange(const QAbstractAxis* axis) {
    switch(axis->type()) {
    case QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeValue:
        const auto valueAxis = static_cast<const QValueAxis*>(axis);
        return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>(valueAxis->min(), valueAxis->max());
    case QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeBarCategory:
        const auto barCategoryAxis = static_cast<const QBarCategoryAxis*>(axis);
        return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>(barCategoryAxis->min(), barCategoryAxis->max());
    case QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeCategory:
        const auto categoryAxis = static_cast<const QCategoryAxis*>(axis);
        return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>(categoryAxis->min(), categoryAxis->max());
    case QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeDateTime:
        const auto dateTimeAxis = static_cast<const QDateTimeAxis*>(axis);
        return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>(dateTimeAxis->min(), dateTimeAxis->max());
    case QAbstractAxis::AxisTypeLogValue:
        const auto logValueAxis = static_cast<const QValueAxis*>(axis);
        return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>(logValueAxis->min(), logValueAxis->max());
    }

    qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO << ": Unknown axis type: " << axis->type();
    return QPair<QVariant, QVariant>();
}
```

Check if type of range is your favorite type:

```
const auto& range = axisRange(axis);
bool ok;
const qreal min = range.first.toReal(&ok);
const qreal max = range.second.toReal(&ok);
if (ok) {
    // It's a real deal.
} else {
    // Not my type.
}
```